# How to count the number of older time stamps for each row (id) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I am trying to create an aggregation by counting the number of historical incidents per unique ID based on date

```
ID   Date 
1    1/1/2010
1    1/1/2011
1    1/1/2012
2    1/1/2010
2    1/1/2011
```

The desired output would be:

```
ID   Date      Historical_Incidents
1    1/1/2010  0
1    1/1/2011  1
1    1/1/2012  2
2    1/1/2010  0
2    1/1/2011  1
```

I tried first grouping by ID, and counting the number of unique dates then merging with the orginal dataframe:

`data4.groupby('Id')['Date'].nunique()`

I'm gettting the number of "Dates" per ID, but I'm trying to get the number of "Dates" which occured before per id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making similar, but non-identical data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[2009, 1], [2010, 1], [2011, 1], [2009, 2], [2010, 2]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df
      A  B
0  2009  1
1  2010  1
2  2011  1
3  2009  2
4  2010  2
```

Assuming they are all sorted by date (here, the `A` column):

```
>>> df['count'] = df.groupby('B').cumcount()
>>> df
      A  B  count
0  2009  1      0
1  2010  1      1
2  2011  1      2
3  2009  2      0
4  2010  2      1
```